# Nested "if", Missing right curly or square bracket

Tags: perl, if-statement

I currently have the following:

```
elsif ($line =~ /^(\s*)(if|elif|else)\s*(.+)*\s*:\s*$/) {
    # Multiline If
    # Print the If/Elif condition
    if ($2 eq "if"){
        print "$1$2 ($3){\n";
    } 
    elsif ($2 eq "elif"){
        print "$1elsif ($3){\n";
    }
    elsif ($2 eq "else"){
        print "$1$2 $3{\n";
    }
    # Add the space before the word "if"/"elif"/"else" to the stack
    push(@indentation_stack, $1);   

}
```

I am getting the stated error, but I'm not sure why. In the final `elsif`, if I add a `\` before the `{` in the `print` statement, the code doesn't generate an error.

I.E:

```
elsif ($2 eq "else"){
        print "$1$2 $3\{\n";
    }
```

Could someone please explain to me why this is occurring?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tricky! The problem is that the following is the start of hash lookup:

```
$3{
```

You want the equivalent of

```
$3 . "{"
```

which can be written as

```
"${3}{"
```

---

The following works in this case because the `\` can't possibly be part of the variable there:

```
"$3\{"
```

But that trick can't always be used. For example, consider

```
$foo . "bar"
```

If you try

```
"$foo\bar"
```

You'll find you get

```
$foo . chr(0x08) . "ar"
```

because `"\b"` returns the "bell" character. That leaves you with

```
"${foo}bar"
```